# Why is the mining reward lock time set to 60 blocks?

Tags: mining, block-reward, transaction-unlock-time

What is the rational behind the mining reward lock time constant having been set to 60 blocks?

Comment: It is not set to 100 blocks. It is set to 60 blocks.

Comment: Any ideas about why it's set to 60 blocks?

Comment: I could only guess, the original authors are Bytecoin/Cryptonote.